# ¿Cómo crear o instalar un servidor UDP/NTP de hora en Windows?

Tags: php, c++, c, redes, tcp

Estoy hace 3 semanas con esto y no puedo mas, ya no sé que hacer.

Tengo una computadora con windows que será mi servidor local (100% local - Jamás se conectará a internet) y tengo dispositivos que van a necesitar que alguien les diga la hora.

Intenté crear script PHP cómo servidor de hora (a través de UDP) y fracasé, o sea, me funcionaba desde el navegador del propio servidor y desde el navegador de otras computadoras en la misma red local pero nunca haciendo uso de programas como Packet Sender (yo seleccionaba UDP, IP, PUERTO y nunca anduvo).

Ahora estoy pensando que quizás exista un programa que se instale en windows y luego a través de scripts clientes (haciendo uso de cualquier lenguaje de programación) se pueda hacer una petición UDP a esa IP y PUERTO y me devuelva la hora.

¿Aún no entendes lo que necesito?

Un servidor de hora en RED LOCAL para WINDOWS, que me devuelva la hora cuando un dispositivo la requiera

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

debes iniciar el servicio "Hora de Windows" y en el firewall crear una regla de entrada que permita la conexión al puerto `UDP 123`. Para lo primero sigue estos pasos:

1. Abre el editor de registro de Windows (ejecuta `regedit.exe`) y navega a `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer]`, una vez allí cambia a `1` el valor de la propiedad `Enabled`.
2. Luego abre una ventana de símbolo de sistema (ejecuta `cmd.exe`) con privilegios administrativos.
3. Iniciar el servicio "Hora de Windows":
   `net start w32time`
4. Configurar el servicio de para que se ejecute automáticamente:
   `sc config "w32time" start=auto`
5. Actualizar la configuración del servidor de hora:
   `w32tm /config /update`
6. Verificar el estado del servidor:
   `w32tm /query /configuration`
7. Crea la regla de entrada en el firewall:
   `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Conexión a servidor de Hora" protocol=UDP dir=in localport=123 action=allow`

En resumen lo que debes hacer es ejecutar las siguientes líneas desde una ventana de símbolo de sistema (ejecuta `cmd.exe`) con privilegios administrativos:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
net start w32time
sc config "w32time" start=auto
w32tm /config /update
w32tm /query /configuration
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Conexión a servidor de Hora" protocol=UDP dir=in localport=123 action=allow
```

Comment: muchas gracias por editar la respuesta, ahora es de ayuda la información para la comunidad!, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo intentaré y luego te cuento.